# Horizontal alignement of axis environments inside tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, axis

How to horizontally align multiple (3+) `axis` environments inside one `tikzpicture` with the same spacing between them?

Note that I need to have another `tikzpicture` on top this `tikzpicture`, with everything inside one `figure` environment.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

NS

Comment: Yes, but you might want to have a look at the `groupplots` library of pgfplots.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99181/how-to-align-pgfplot-subplots/99203#99203 for one example, here is another showing both `groupplots` and how to position an `axis` relative to another `axis`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311161/pgfplots-shift-the-entire-axis-environment-to-the-right/311850#311850

Comment: OK, thank you! I will check it. I found a hack in the meantime but it doesn't perfectly align the elements; was just playing with `hspace`.